# Must I synchronise read and write operations when doing it from different goroutines?

Tags: http, go, concurrency, goroutine

As I know, every requests to the server creates new goroutine. For ex (probably incorrect code, but this topic is not about it):

package main

```
import "net/http"

var exampleMap map[string]string 

func handlerPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        {
            exampleMap["test"] = test // Must I syncrhonise this writing?
        }
    case "GET":
        {
            if v, ok := exampleMap["test"] { // And what about reading?
                fmt.Println(v)
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handlerPost)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Does it mean that its unsafe to do it like this and I have to use sync.Map (for example), and what about if instead map here was a database queries? What can I do in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`exampleMap` is shared among goroutines, so you have to synchronize access to it. A mutex would do, a RWMutex would perform better:

```
var exampleMap map[string]string 
var exampleMutex sync.RWMutex

...
exampleMutex.Lock()
exampleMap["test"] = test 
exampleMutex.Unlock()
...
exampleMutex.RLock()
v, ok := exampleMap["test"] 
exampleMutex.RUnlock()
if ok {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks! Must I do something similar when reading/writing from/to database?

Comment: Usually databases do this kind of access control themselves.

Comment: If you are working with SQL databases, and using a package (or derivative) that relies on Go's [standard sql](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Open) package then no, you do not have to add mutexes for synchronization, as the Database objects returned by Go's sql package are safe for concurrent use.